# Compile-time constant discrepency

Tags: c#

**Update:** This appears to be a compiler red-herring, as the following is actually valid:

```
const int MyInt = default(int);
```

The issue lies with `DateTime` not being a valid `const`, not the use of `default`.

The main source of the confusion for me was not realising that `default(DateTime)` is handled specifically in optional parameters (and I had arrived at a false conclusion that `default(DateTime)` was being treated as compile-time constant due to the error message omitting the other possible conditions). This is addressed by MarcinJuraszek in his answer.

---

**Original Question:**

<sub>This is shamelessly ripped from a comment from Marc Gravell from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18740465/358221) to another question.</sub>

Why is the following valid:

```
// No compiler errors, default(DateTime) seems to satisfy the compile-time constant requirement.
public static void DoSomething(DateTime date = default(DateTime))
{ 
}
```

But the following not:

```
// Compiler error: "Constant initializer must be compile-time constant.
const DateTime MyDate = default(DateTime);
```

As both appear to want "compile-time constants" (evident if you attempt to provide something like `DateTime.MinValue` to the optional parameter, the compiler complains that it isn't compile-time constant):

```
// Compiler error: Default parameter value for 'date' must be a compile-time constant.
public static void DoSomething(DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue) {}
```

What is going on behind the scenes that causes the compiler to treat these differently?

Comment: optional parameters were added after the fact.

Comment: Look at the compiler message. Is probably tells you something.

Comment: @DanielA.White - so was `default`, IIRC. It was only added when generics were.

Comment: @usr Well, the compiler message is the source of the confusion mate.

Comment: It would appear that it is part of the spec. I really should read that more thoroughly at some point!!

Comment: @usr Following on from your comment, the build error messages state that `DateTime` isn't a valid const, but the in-IDE error message jumps to the `default` issue, a red-herring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a `const` that can only have the value `default(TypeOfCost)` would probably be quite useless :-)... And you can't even change it later :-)

Note that `default(TypeOfConst)` **is** a constant-expression

From the C# specifications (5.0): `7.19 Constant expressions`... `A constant-expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile-time.`... `Only the following constructs are permitted in constant expressions:`... `•  **Default value expressions**`

The error is that `const DateTime` is illegal..

`10.4 Constants`... `The type specified in a constant declaration must be sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, bool, string, an enum-type, or a reference-type.`

Comment: Agreed, but the definition of `default(DateTime)` being "compile-time constant" in one situation and not in another is in question, not its use ;-)

Comment: PI can only have the value 3.14... but I still think it's usefull.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth The error I get is `The type 'System.DateTime' cannot be declared const`

Comment: @xanatos Ah, there are two errors there then, build reports both but the IDE only reports one.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth A more interesting example that you can add is that you can't use `default(DateTime)` as an attribute parameter :-)

Comment: @SWeko PI is one of the 2^64 values of a `double` and it can't be calculated easily. `default(ReferenceType)` == null, `default(ValueType)` == "zeroed ValueType". They are quite simple results.

Comment: @xanatos Is that "default value expressions" specifically `default(type)` or literal defaults like `int i = 1;`?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth `7.6.13 Default value expressions`... `default-value-expression:`... `default   (   type   )`. Quite clear, I think

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth The limit is in the `const` that can't be used with `DateTime`. I've found the piece of specifications that tells it. Probably they thought that `default(ValueType)` was quite useless (and as a singleton constant value calculable at compile time) and so they limited the `const`.

Comment: @xanatos Yes, the same issue occurs with attribute parameters re your comment above, `default(int)` is valid in an attribute parameter. It appears that this compiler error message trumps the one about attempting to use `DateTime` in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

That's described in C# specification (10.6.1):

> A *fixed-parameter* with a *default-argument* is known as an ***optional
>   parameter***, whereas a *fixed-parameter* without a *default-argument* is a
>   ***required parameter***. A required parameter may not appear after an
>   optional parameter in a *formal-parameter-list*.
>
> A `ref` or `out`parameter cannot have a *default-argument*. The *expression* in a *default-argument*
>   must be one of the following:
>
> - a constant-expression
> - an expression of the form `new S()` where `S` is a value type
> - an expression of the form `default(S)` where `S` is a value type

But you're right, the error message asking for *compile-time constant* is not good.

Comment: You should also say that default is an operator evaluated at runtime, then this answer is perfect

Comment: @Marcin 7.19 of the C# specifications (5.0): 7.19 `Constant expressions`... `A constant-expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile-time.`... `Only the following constructs are permitted in constant expressions:`... `• Default value expressions`

Answer (score 4):

`default()` is evaluated at runtime. `DateTime.MinValue` is not declared as const.

Only symbols declared as const can be used in member initialisation and attribute declarations.

Optional paramters are a special case. The compiler generates overloads for you. Semantically it wants a const, but technically, default is ok as the compiler knows how to use this in the generated overload.

MSDN states that optional parameters accept `default()` and `new()` by design http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Concerning the const definition;

> A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at
>   compile time.

I agree that the distinction is slight and it has tripped me up more than once.

Comment: I don't think that covers the question. I know `DateTime.MinValue` is not constant, but in one situation `default(DateTime)` is and in another situation it "isn't".

Comment: 7.19 of the C# specifications (5.0): 7.19 `Constant expressions`... `A constant-expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile-time.`... `Only the following constructs are permitted in constant expressions:`... `• Default value expressions`